# file_get_contents($url): failed to open stream error while trying to access a url directly

Tags: file-get-contents

In my laravel app I installed `stevebauman/location": "1.3.*`

It works just fine in my local server. After I uploaded it to the remote server, this line

`$contents = json_decode(file_get_contents($this->url.$ip), true);`

in the file

`F:\xampp\htdocs\news5.2.23\vendor\stevebauman\location\src\Drivers\FreeGeoIp.php`

is throwing the error I mentioned.

I searched a lot and tried the following:

- I echoed the $url and then copied and directly put in browser, it's all right.
- `allow_ini_set("allow_url_include", "on");ini_set("allow_url_fopen", "on");` wrote it in index.php
- used curl .I will provide the FreeGeoIp Class whereI used curl for testing

  ```
  <?php
      namespace Stevebauman\Location\Drivers;

      use Stevebauman\Location\Objects\Location;
      use Stevebauman\Location\Location as LocationInstance;

      class FreeGeoIp implements DriverInterface
      {
          /**
           * Holds the current Location class instance.
           *
           * @var LocationInstance
          */
          private $instance;

          /**
           * Holds the configuration instance.
           *
           * @var \Illuminate\Config\Repository
          */
          private $config;

          /*
           * Holds the drivers URL
           */
          private $url;

          /**
           * Constructor.
           *
           * @param LocationInstance $instance
          */
          public function __construct(LocationInstance $instance)
          {
              $this->instance = $instance;

              $this->config = $this->instance->getConfig();

              $this->url = $this->config->get('location.drivers.FreeGeoIp.url');
          }

          /**
           * Retrieves the location from the driver FreeGeoIp and returns a    location object.
           *
           * @param string $ip
           *
           * @return Location
          */
           public function get($ip){

               $location = new Location();
               $file = $this->file_get_contents_curl(urlencode($this->url.$ip));
               die();       

              return $location;
          }

          public function file_get_contents_curl($url) {

              $ch = curl_init($url);
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
              var_dump($ch);
              $data = curl_exec($ch);
              if($errno = curl_errno($ch)) {
                  $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
                  echo "cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}.</br>";
              }
              curl_close($ch);
              return $data;
          }
      }
  ```

Then I found this error

> cURL error (6): Couldn't resolve host name.

Finally I got somewhere that maybe the server *my site is in has a firewall which is blocking outsourced url call*.  **I dont know why that would be!**

Interestingly when I tried `return redirect('http://freegeoip.lwan.ws/json/visitor_ip')` - this line in a function of one of my Controllers, it worked!

So I have to discard the firewall issue also right?

But when I use `file_get_contents('http://freegeoip.lwan.ws/json/visitor_ip')` in the same function, it doesn't work again.

**People seem to be answering my question without reading it at all. Giving me answers which I already tried and mentioned.Please read.**

Answer (score 0):

enable allow_url_fopen from your php.ini file

Comment: It's in my clients shared hosting. How can I change php.ini there?

Comment: ask your service provider.

Comment: they wont let me change it..what is the other way.. besides, I set it in my application.

Comment: I edited my question, i already tried that page you suggested.

Comment: dd()  the URL in your method "file_get_contents_curl", copy the URL, paste it into the browser, does it work?

Comment: another solution is: http://paste.ubuntu.com/16182408/ ..... Copied from postman's generated code.